# Optional parameters in Cucumber-JS

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters, gherkin, cucumberjs

Hello I am using cucumber-js and I´d like to have just one step re-usable for more than a single scenario taking into account that the parameters are optional.

```
feature file:

      Scenario: with no parameters
        Given I provide "0" parametes:
        When anything
        Then anithing
      
      Scenario: with 1 parameters
        Given I provide "1" parametes:"parameter1"
        When anything
        Then anithing
        
      Scenario: with 2 parameters
        Given I provide "2" parametes:"parameter1", "parameter2"
        When anything
        Then anithing
```

I'd like to have only one step definition for the 3 scenarios. I put something like this, but this step definition is only valid for "with 2 parameters" scenario.

step-definition file in JS:

```
Given(/^I provide "([^"]*)" parametes:"([^"]*)", "([^"]*)"$/, function (optionalParam1, optionalParam2) {

});
```

or like this:

```
Given('I provide {string} parametes:{string}, {string}', function (paramQuantity, optionalParam1, optionalParam2) {

});
```

Can somone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the best way to do this is in your code rather than in the feature file.

You can follow a format in feature files and process it in the step definition.

feature file:

```
  Scenario: with no parameters
    Given I provide " " as parameters
    When anything
    Then anything
  
  Scenario: with 1 parameter
    Given I provide "parameter1" as parameters
    When anything
    Then anything
    
  Scenario: with 2 parameters
    Given I provide "parameter1,parameter2" as parameters
    When anything
    Then anything
```

step definition:

```
Given(/^I provide "([^"]*)" parametes:"([^"]*)", "([^"]*)"$/, function (optionalParam1, optionalParam2) {});
```

Comment: thanks for answering Raju. But, what is the step definition that satisfy these three scenarios?

Comment: Hey @GermanLarcher, edited my answer. Please check if that works. I could not test. if you still face issues, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Raju, thanks for your responses my friend. It seems to work but in this way:  given(/^I provide "([^"]*)" as parameters$/, function (optionalParam1, optionalParam2) {

}); Anyway, I've been traying with dataTables and it seems to be a better solution since you can pass any amount of parameters and then you can convert the table into an array. So thanks Raju!! :) Regards